# Nested foreach loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, foreach

I have a problem with the for-each loop on a practice page.

There are 4 different popups on my page and all of them got a close button. So i wrote this lines four times into my html-code:

```
<div class="description-modal dm-1">
<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close-m" id="close-m-1"></i>
<h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

To activate them I gave them ID's from 1 to 4 and added the class "active" on click.
To close them I tried to use this foreach loop:

```
const modals_all = document.querySelectorAll('.description-modal');
const close_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-m')


modals_all.forEach(modal =>{
  close_buttons.forEach(close_button =>{
    close_button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      if (modal.classList.contains('active')){
        modal.classList.remove('active')
      } else {
        return
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work and i have no idea why, cause the console doesn't show an error. What's the right way to solve this?

Comment: And no need for loops at all with event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match between the button and the modal it belongs. This is done by selecting the button that's inside it.

```js
const modals_all = document.querySelectorAll('.description-modal');
// const close_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-m')

modals_all.forEach(modal => {
  var close_button = modal.querySelector('.close-m')
  close_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (modal.classList.contains('active')) {
      modal.classList.remove('active')
    } else {
      return
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.description-modal {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.description-modal.active {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="description-modal active dm-1">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close-m" id="close-m-1">close</i> &larr;click
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>

<div class="description-modal active dm-1">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close-m" id="close-m-2">close</i> &larr;click
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>

<div class="description-modal active dm-1">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close-m" id="close-m-3">close</i> &larr;click
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Just read this after writing my answer, I entirely agree with this post! No need for nested loops for this.

Comment: Dennibl, if it worked you can accept his answer as correct so if other people find this page with the same issue they can see where to find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need nested loops to do this. Just one loop on the modals should suffice? I would just loop the modals and get the close button as a child element of the modal.

I have not tested this code but I think something similar to this should help you out:

```
const modals_all = document.querySelectorAll('.description-modal');

modals_all.forEach(modal =>{
  let closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.close-m');

  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(modal.classList.contains('active') || modal.style.display === 'block'){
      modal.classList.remove('active');
      //modal.style.display = 'none';
    };
  });

});
```

Just make sure the CSS is also doing what you expect too, otherwise adding and removing classes will not do what you expect. I hope this helps.